# Maxima: generating a list of nouns with "multi-dimensional" subscripts

Tags: list, subscript, maxima

I want to generate a list of subscripted nouns where the subscripts are "multi-dimensional".

For instance, using the two following lists as input:

```
[1,5,2]
[3,5,1]
```

I want to generate the following list:

```
[a[3,1],a[5,5],a[1,2]]
```

Here is a working example:

```
(%i1) indexX : [1,5,2];
(%i2) indexY : [3,5,1];
(%i3) makelist(a[i], i, indexX);
(%i4) map(endcons, indexY, %);

(%o1) [1,5,2]
(%o2) [3,5,1]
(%o3) [a[1],a[5],a[2]]
(%o4) [a[3,1],a[5,5],a[1,2]]
```

That works, but it requires two lines (call to `makelist()` then to `map()`). Hence it is not very elegant.

Is there a better way to achieve similar results?

Note: Arrays are not suitable for the job because 1. indices can be negative numbers and 2. I don't want to allocate memory for all indices between `[1,1]` and `[5,5]` since I am only using a few of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(%i1) display2d: false $
(%i2) indexX : [1,5,2] $
(%i3) indexY : [3,5,1] $
(%i4) map(lambda([[L]], arraymake('a, L)), indexX, indexY);
(%o4) [a[1,3],a[5,5],a[2,1]]
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution you have. However, I am a bit confused : is there a difference between an underscripted noun and an array element ? Does a call to `arraymake()` generates an array or merely a single noun ?

Comment: @GLorieul [arraymake](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html#IDX142) returns an unevaluated expression. You can also consider [subvar](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html#IDX150)

Comment: ok, so your solution suits me well. I am still confused about what maxima calls an array, but I'll post that as a new stackoverflow question (that seems to be the most appropriate thing to do).